# ZF2, strategy design pattern on controller with multiple if-elseifs

Tags: php, zend-framework

In ZF2, I have the controller factory that instantiates the controller. The controller displays and processes 6 forms. The forms share the same `name` of the submit button, but have different submit `value`s.

The forms get processed in the controllers `indexAction()` using multiple `if-elseif`s based on the value of the form's submit button.

I'd like to get rid of `if-elseif`s. I guess I need to use the strategy design pattern on the controller's factory class. Problem is that I somehow need to pass the value of the submit button into the controller factory.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to pass this into the controller is to `use Zend\Http\Request;`. With the request object you can then get the posted value.

BUT! After digging, found 2 resources:

1. http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/ZF2-Injecting-objects-to-a-controller-or-getting-objects-from-the-service-locator-td4656872.html. Here @weierophinney (one of the main contributors to the Zend framework) suggests a couple of guidelines:

> The rule of thumb I have is: more than 5-7 actions in a controller:
>   refactor. More than 1-2 forms: refactor. Otherwise, the workflow of the
>   controller becomes too difficult to follow easily.

If your actions in the controller use the same form, you can set `setValidationGroup()` and with this validate different parts of the form depending on the action.

So for my case, I guess, I need to refactor the controller to separate out the forms.

2. http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/zf2-widget-base-app-logic-td4657457.html. Here @weierophinney suggests using view helpers for the forms.